# What are these properties added onto the token response used for?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm studying authentication on ASP.NET WebAPI 2 with OAuth 2.0 using OWIN middlewares and I'm in doubt about some additional properties sent together with the token response on the VS template.

Basically in the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class we find these two methods:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "userName", userName }
    };
    return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
}
```

The first one, picks the data found on `context.Properties` and add to the response and the second adds a single property `userName` to the response creating an `AuthenticationProperties` object. This object is then used to create an `AuthenticationTicket` and with it the response contains not just the token, but those additional properties as well.

My doubts are: first, what are those properties found on `context.Properties` and why do we bother sending then together with the token? Second, what this `AuthenticationProperties` types is for, and why do we send just an `userName` using it? What this type can be used for?

I'm confused with those additional properties because I thought the only important thing to get from the server was the token. Is there some deeper reason to send those properties? Or we just send them to provide extra data for the front-end, like giving the username back so that the client can display it somewhere?

Comment: Have you figured it out yourself finally or are you still wondering?